# Unable to run self-test suite

Tags: sonos

unable to run self test suite, when trying to run, i am getting below error

```
 python suite_selftest.py --config "C:\Users\Arul\Downloads\PythonSelfTest\smapi\service_configs\smapiConfig.cfg"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "suite_selftest.py", line 13, in <module>
    from utility import ServiceConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\Arul\Downloads\PythonSelfTest\smapi\content_workflow\utility.py", line 84
    except ItemNotFound, w:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting SyntaxError it looks like you're trying to execute the self-test suite with Python 3.x, it needs to be run with Python 2.7+!